# why multiparty.Form() is creating some temporary image file after upload?

Tags: node.js, multipartform-data

I am trying to upload image through Node.js but while uploading image, the same image is creating with some temporary name **G-fMNpe9OCU3NdLzPxnRT-X2.png** like this but i am able to upload image i am not finding any issue to upload image but i have only one question why the same is image creating again with these names ?

**My Code**

```
 router.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    var multiparty = require("multiparty");
    var form = new multiparty.Form();
    var fs = require('fs');

    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {

        var img = files.images[0];
        var value = fields.value[0];

    fs.readFile(img.path, function (err, data) {

    /*********************Upload Image to S3Bucket**********************/
      var params = {
        Bucket: 'abcd',
        Key: img.originalFilename,
        Body: data
    };

      s3.putObject(params, function (perr, pres) {
        if (perr) {
            console.log("Error uploading data: ", perr);
        } else {
             res.redirect('/');
            console.log("Successfully uploaded data to Bucket");
        }
    });
  /*******************************************************************/             
});
});});
```

Please kindly suggest me some solution

Answer (score 0):

You're not deleting the uploaded file after you're done with it. It's not like with PHP where the files are automatically deleted if you don't move/delete them yourself.

Comment: `fs.unlink(img.path, function(err) { /* ... */ })` inside your `readFile()` callback.